# Different result during Debug and Run in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, short-circuiting

I wrote this small piece of code to test Short-circuit operator

```
package com.MasterChief;

public class ShortCircuitDebugTest {
    static boolean myBool = true;
    static int myInt = 1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (myBool || myFunc()){ // line 7: put break point here
            System.out.println("myInt = " + myInt);
        }
    }

    private static boolean myFunc(){
        myInt = 5;
        return !myBool;
    }
}
```

I put a Breakpoint at line 7 and added **myFunc** in the *Expressions* window. During debug *Expressions* window should be visible. Result is:

```
myInt = 5
```

If I just run the program or do not add **myFunc** in *Expressions* window or do not select *Expressions* window, I do not get this behaviour.
Is this is an expected behaviour or a bug in Eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add the expression to the expression Window it will executed and change the value of the global variables `myBool`and `myInt`. If you go to the next step it will executed a second time and so your code will give you an other result.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug. Since `||` operator evaluates expressions from left to right your `myBool` check will return true and the `myFunc()` will NOT get called (since the entire condition will always be true there is no need to evaluate `myFunc()` result).

Since you use the `myFunc()` in the debug expressions window it will be evaluated nonetheless to show you the result and will change the `myInt` to `5`.